# Is there a situation when WsFederationAuthenticationOptions WReply and CallbackPath values may not match?

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, ws-federation, katana

When using ASP.Net OWIN/Katana to set up single sign-on using WSFederation, there exists `WReply` and `CallbackPath` properties.

In example projects, these appear to have very similar values when configured within `Startup.Auth`, e.g.:

```
new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions() {
   CallbackPath = "/WsFed-Foo", 
   Wreply = "https://example.com/WsFed-Foo"
```

Looking at the docs, I see this:

> CallbackPath must be set to match or cleared so it can be generated
> dynamically. This field is optional. If not set then it will be
> generated from the current request and the CallbackPath.

I appreciate that `CallbackPath` is optional, but if it needs to match `WReply`, then why does the Katana have it when it is computed automatically if omitted?  Is there a situation where it might be different to WReply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what Tratcher posted in Github (https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1645) answers your question?

In case it does, his reply there to the "WsFed confusion between Wreply and CallbackPath #1645" issue was:

> When WsFed was ported from Katana it was translation with modest
> updates, most of the original design and options were preserved.
> Justin noticed in testing that the modified relationship between
> CallbackPath and Wreply is confusing and may cause infinite login
> loops for our customers. **Wreply sets the address the identity
> provider returns to. CallbackPath sets the path the middleware listens
> on for the reply.**
>
> In Katana users could opt to set Wreply and CallbackPath would be
> derived from that. Neither had a default and if it wasn't set then the
> middleware would read all form-post requests.
>
> In Core CallbackPath defaults to /signin-wsfed like our other handlers
> and Wreply has no value. Challenges generate a wreply from the
> CallbackPath. The confusion comes if someone sets wreply without
> updating or clearing CallbackPath. The server will reply to a path
> that the handler isn't listening on, likely resulting in an infinite
> auth loop or 404.
>
> **The motivation for making wreply a public option on WsFed rather than generating the redirect like other providers was that WsFed
> identity servers were known to be extremely strict on matching the
> value, to the point of requiring exact casing, etc.. Generating the
> url from user input may not be sufficient for this check.** It's
> unclear how many customers have run into this mismatch vs those that
> set wreply because they saw it in a sample.
>
> Not sure what the best path forward here is. We'll see how many users
> run into it.

I added emphasys to what I think may answer your first question. Regarding your second question, there doesn't seem to be a situation where it makes sense for Wreply and CallbackPath to be incompatible. (Technically, they are always different because CallbackPath - unlike Wreply - is not a full URL.)

Comment: Thank you.  It's not the "ideal" answer but it is an answer and provides enough clarity on the *why*